# Better way to group by category and include full category entry

Tags: templating, categories, performance, queries, group

The basic idea is that I want to group my entries by category, but I want more than just the category title—I need the entire category entry. [My previous post alludes to this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17706/ordering-related-items-by-cp-display-order), but I've since discovered the query I was doing there was returning all related entries regardless of their existance in the `block.result` entry.

I'm currently doing this—which is exactly what I want, but it doesn't see very efficient... Is there a better way?

```
{% set results = block.result %}
{% for category, catEntries in results | group('infographicSection.first().title') %}
    {% set fullCat = craft.categories.title(category).first() %}
    <h1 class="{{fullCat.className}}">{{fullCat.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{fullCat.body}}</p>
    <ul>
    {% for entry in catEntries %}

        <li>{{entry.title}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements  should help reduce queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual code is pretty effective – the problem is that it's potentially going to result in *a lot* of queries.

This is a good example of the so-called *N+1* query problem, where each iteration over the result set of a single query generates an additional number of queries. Depending on the number of elements involved, this issue can easily result in hundreds of queries, which can be a huge problem for performance.

The solution to the N+1 query problem is [eager loading](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements). With eager loading, you explicitly tell Craft which relational data it should include with the first query, unlike with the common "lazy loading" pattern where relational data is queried on a "need to use" basis.

Here's how your code could look, refactored to use eager loading:

```
{% set results = block.result.find({
    with: ['infographicSection']
}) %}

{% for category, catEntries in results|group('infographicSection[0].title') %}
    {% set fullCat = catEntries[0].infographicSection[0] %}
    <h1 class="{{fullCat.className}}">{{fullCat.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{fullCat.body}}</p>
    <ul>
        {% for entry in catEntries %}
            <li>{{entry.title}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

With something like the above, you should see the number of queries drop drastically (remember to turn on [`devMode`](https://craftcms.com/support/dev-mode) in development and you'll see a profiling report in your browser's dev tools console, containing the total number of queries).

Comment: That's surprisingly easy! Thanks for the great response. Just noticing you're using the `[0]` syntax—is that a stylistic change or will that also be improving performance?

Comment: The brackets syntax is actually required with eager loading. The reason is that when you eager load a relational field (such as Entries, Assets or Categories), that field will no longer return an [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) instance, but a regular ol' array. The `.first()` method belongs to the ElementCriteriaModel class, and doesn't exist for arrays – hence the `[0]` instead. For an even better explanation, [check out the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements#accessing-eager-loaded-elements) :)